# Could not find androidx.camera:camera-view

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camera2, android-camerax

I am developing a basic custom camera app
These are my dependency

```
// CameraX core library dependency
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camera_version"
// CameraX Lifecycle dependency
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camera_version"
// CameraX View dependency
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:$camera_version"
```

camera_version = '1.0.0'

Getting below error, it work fine if I remove camera-view dependency, but I cannot as I need that for my custom camera app.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find androidx.camera:camera-view.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/camera/camera-view/1.0.0/camera-view-1.0.0.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/camera/camera-view/1.0.0/camera-view-1.0.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :app

Comment: From: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera `androidx.camera.view` is at version `1.0.0-alpha24` what happens if you hardcode that version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Morrison Chang already helped you with current issue.
I just wanted to add a few pointers to that whenever you get any such error in future for any of the android's library.

- Search google's maven repo https://maven.google.com/ to see if the version you are looking for is even the correct one or what is the latest version of the library exists. like in your case https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=camera#androidx.camera:camera-view
- Few of the library is still available at https://mvnrepository.com/ where you can check the version of your library